# I need to build a high current, low voltage buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, high-current, low-voltage

I am trying to power a 14 mΩ resistive load at 0.3 V  21.5 A to add some buffer to the design I'm trying to design for 30 A, since the load can change.

Without going too in depth the load is a new special designed glow-plug for high performance engine - if needed I can explain why the solution the maker proposes is not sufficient.

The circuit should run off a 1S LiPo (maximum voltage 4.2V.)

- Vin_max: 4.2 V
- I_out_max: 30 A
- Switching frequency: 160 kHz (I don't need a fast time response so it could also be lower.)

Can this even be done?

The duty cycle will be around 7% (0.07), which is not a lot. Should I make 2 converters in series? One to lower the voltage from 4.2 V to 2 V and another to from 2 V to 0.3 V.

When I looked for ICs to use, I ran in the the problem that most of them can only go as low as 0.6-0.8 V due the their internal reference.

I'm planning to make a test circuit with the following components:

- Driver: TPS28225D ( half-bridge, high-/low-side, gate driver) (*will be supplied externally for now*)
- MOSFET: AOT2140L (Rds_on: 2 mΩ)
- Inductor: MPXV1D1770LR68 (ferrite, 680 nH, Ioper: 50A, 1.05 mΩ, ±20%, Isat:68 A)
- Controller: Atmel microcontroller - I have ideas for extra features, and I know how to program it pretty well (it will be supplied externally for now.)

I tried to pick components with as small a resistance as I could to minimize the thermal load and losses in the converter.

1. Are there any problems with the combination of components?
2. Should I design the test circuit on a PCB or can I lay it out on "proto-board"?
3. Is there a different design I should consider? (Multi-phase, serial coupling, other.)

As a side note I should mention that I'm an electrical engineer but I have not done anything with buck converters or power delivery before. I do have a fundamental understanding of the basics (I think/hope.)

[image: Simplified Schematic TPS28225D]

[image: 4 Point measurement of the load]

[image: 4 Point measurement of the load]

Comment: I'd check out some CPU voltage regulators for use on PC motherboards. Sub 1V, low duty cycle,  multi phase... They tick all the boxes.

Comment: For example, [TPS53676](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS53676).

Comment: Practical limit is about 20 A per phase. At 30 A, a two-phase would be a suitable option.

Comment: _"Should I design the test circuit on a PCB or can I lay it out on "proto-board"?"_ A 30 A buck converter will not work on a proto board. You need a devboard or make your own PCB with proper decoupling and ground plane.

Comment: How does the resistance of the glow plug change with temperature? Does it have a lower resistance when cold? Do you need a soft-start? How is temperature regulated? Can it be current driven or does it have to be voltage? And... Have you considered a transformer? I mean it's a resistor, it should work on AC, so a transformer fed from a high frequency H-bridge seems like an ideal and cheap solution for this step down ratio.

Comment: I suggest treating this as a current source rather than a voltage source - now you don't need an output capacitor and also your control algorithm will be simpler. I think. I am not experienced in high-current buck converter design neither.

Comment: @user253751 It depends! If the glow plug regulates temperature with PTC resistance, constant current would cause it to overheat.

Comment: 1oz copper is 0.5mOhm/square. That’s 28 squares to have as much resistance as the glow plug. I.e. *any* 1oz polygon that’s 28 times as long as it’s wide, no matter how wide, will have 14mOhm resistance. Due to current concentrations around the component pads, the effective sheet resistance goes up. So using up many squares is all too easy. You’ll need 2oz or even 3oz copper and perhaps 4 layers, with several layers paralleled by a via “kelp forest”.  Currents around pads must be spread to parallel layers close to pad. Vapor reflow soldering is preferred to minimize stresses then AFAIK.

Comment: I know you specified an output voltage, but would it be acceptable to control the output current instead.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica ...or use a transformer with the thick secondary wire going directly to the glow plug.

Comment: I used a CSD95373BQ5M as power stage for such a converter, but a small step up converter for the 5V gate driver circuit is needed. Using two of them with 180° phase shift enables a less critical layout and a broader range of matching inductors.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fundamental understanding now, you will be an expert when you finish this design!

*Are there any problems with the combination of components?*  Well, there are things to watch out for:

AOT2140L: Like all muscular MOSFETS, the AOT2140L handles high current at a price: large capacitances.  In this case, the gate capacitance is 10 nF, so you will need as much current (and voltage) as you can get in the drive side, and you have to have an adequate bootstrap capacitor and diode.  I might add a separate external Schottky.  You'll need short wide traces not only for your current paths but also for your gate drive power/decoupling traces and the gate drive signal itself.  Any inductance or resistance in the gate path will cause the part to oscillate at the switch point, costing efficiency and heat.

TPS28225D: You won't be able to run this circuit with 4.2 volts, because the internal bootstrap diode in these parts require 1 volt, leaving only 3.2 volts for the bootstrap.  Once again, an external Schottky would help some, but even so this will be too close to the FET gate threshold voltage and the switching times will suffer.  You can try running the device with a separate, 8 volt power source.  Use big decoupling capacitors near the part, because you have to supply 2 amps to the gate.

MPXV1D1770LR68:  Be sure and calculate the maximum current you expect to see in the inductor; you can't use the average.  If your instantaneous current approaches the saturation point, you will experience high current spikes.  This same warning applies to your battery/power capacitor combination.  Also, there will be a considerable resistance increase in the inductor winding due to skin effect; do not expect the apparent resistance to be that in the spec sheet.

*Should I design the test circuit on a PCB or can I lay it out on "proto-board"?*  No luck here.

Your best chance is to use a circuit board that you lay out yourself, with wide areas for traces and possibly conductors on multiple traces connected by multiple vias.  Remember, you are switching 30 amps, so both resistance and inductance of your current paths come into play.  You'll want low ESR decoupling capacitors, and I might lay out for a snubber just in case.

*Is there a different design I should consider? (Multi-phase, serial coupling, other.)*  Of course there is more than one way to skin this cat, but I see no problem with your approach, and you should have some fun with it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - I'm at the point of becoming an expert where I realize I don't know anything :)


On the PCB - I plan to solder thick strips of copper/brass to carry the 30A.

Regarding the mosfet and the external Schottky - is this external Schottky in paralelle with the mosfet body diode? Why is that needed?


TPS28225D: Sizing boot strap cap is an exercise in it self, but you mention a diode, my understanding was that this diode is internal in the IC?

Comment: You can add a diode between VDD and BOOT and it will be in parallel with the internal diode, with better performance.  I was never meaning the body diode.  Solder strips might work if you are an artist, but I would recommend doing a layout.  Try looking at some reference designs or evaluation board layouts for these types of converters at your current levels and you can get a good shot at getting it right.  A lot of the board houses have their own free-to-use proprietary layout apps and you can get a few boards for 100 bucks or so.

Comment: check out https://www.onsemi.com/design/tools-software/evaluation-board/ncp3230gevb - You might even get by with it but you can at least see how it's laid out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation of a simple buck converter that will provide about 30 A into a 40 mOhm resistive load. The MOSFET I chose dissipates about 15 watts at 50 kHz. This is mostly conduction loss, as this device has 25 mOhms ON resistance. Other devices should be available to improve this, or you might add one or two in parallel.

[image: Buck PWM 3.2V 30A]

Using an IRF7210 brings its dissipation down to about 9.5 watts. But there is also about 14 watts in D1. So for 46 watts into the load, efficiency is only about 50%. A 25A Schottky MBRB2545CT brings its dissipation down to about 9.5 watts.

The IRF7210 is obsolete and cannot handle 30A, so an [FDMC610P](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FDMC610P_D-1807704.pdf) should do the job nicely, and is in stock for a couple bucks.

A better approach would probably be a push-pull driver into a center-tapped toroid with about 20 turns, and 2-3 turns on the secondary as needed for the low resistance load.

Comment: Theta(JA) is 50 degC/watt, so 15 watts...